# I don't need saving. How to keep Emacs buffers in sync with files?

Tags: emacs, autosave

I want to have all my file buffers *always* synchronized with the file content on disk.
Is is possible? (preferably as a mode)

If you think it is unsafe, than I will just say that *emacs undo + git* is more than enough for me and I find explicit saving and reverting (if other program changes the file) obsolete safety feature.

Comment: You're going to really shorten the life of the media storing your files.

Comment: Do you want auto-save or do you want auto-revert?

Comment: I want synchronization - i.e. both auto-save and auto-revert.

Comment: Will I shorten the life of the media or will it go through disk cache? How to check it?

Comment: It'll be in disk cache, but depending on your OS, that gets written every 20 seconds or so. I wouldn't worry about it on a hard drive, but a flash-based disk might be more of a concern. Still not a serious one for the better ones though.

Answer (score 9):

To bring it all together:

> If you want auto-saving to be done in the visited file rather than in a separate auto-save file, set the variable `auto-save-visited-file-name` to a non-nil value. In this mode, there is no real difference between auto-saving and explicit saving.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html#Auto-Save-Files

This makes your auto-saves go into the file you are working on, and not an external one.

Then you can set `auto-save-interval` to 1, and enable `global-auto-revert-mode` and you're all set.

I think that does it for you...

Comment: Nice. But I want this only for files that are under git's supervision, is it possible to automatize this?

Comment: You can probably modify your local copy of git.el to enable these changes only when you're editing git controlled files.

Comment: or use something like eproject to configure that on a project-type basis

Answer (score 3):

Set the "auto-save-interval" to 1.  That will save after each character you type.  It will save to the "save" file, rather than the actual file, but your work will be protected.

Another option is this: http://www.litchie.net/programs/real-auto-save.html

Comment: Also see: http://bryan-murdock.blogspot.com/2008/03/beat-save-habit.html , the EmacsWiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave , and (pointlessly): http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/01/22/emacs-auto-save/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [auto-revert-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html) (or more likely global-auto-revert-mode).

Comment: Solves half of the problem, what about global-auto-save-mode?

Comment: Ah, by "I don't need saving" I assumed you never wanted to write to the file.